# Adding Apps on SharePoint 2013 on-premise Server required Microsoft login

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Hello fellow developers,

I've installed SharePoint 2013 on a on-premise farm and configured App on it successfully many times. However, every single I try to add an add it redirect me to the Microsoft Marketplace log in and once I do, I'm then able to add the app to my app catalog for users to then add n their sites.

Is this normal? In all the books and online discussion I've read, once you've configured Apps on the SharePoint server you don't need a third-party "authenticatior". The provider-hosted app server would try to authenticate with my server. I could be wrong, please any wisdom on the topic would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank you Shashank, It does make sense since I am accessing their server to grab the app but none of the book I've read mentioned it; so thank you for putting me at ease..

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine. Whenever you try to get an app from Microsoft's SharePoint store, they need to know your identity. You may install free or paid apps, but the fact that you are getting it from Microsoft's store requires authentication. However, if you have configured an environment for in-house apps (i.e your own app server), you can develop apps and upload to your own personal app catalog (or you may download sample app packages and tweak them according to your requirement). Your in-house apps won't show up in SharePoint store until you create a seller profile and publish them.